# Error al instalar proyecto en symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony3

Hola me han asignado una modificación en un proyecto con **synfony 3.2 y php**, el encargado me doy acceso a un repositorio del cual descargué el proyecto y desde entonces he intentado instalarlo en mi ordenador sin éxito.

La estructura de carpetas está incompleta **(falta vendor y algunos archivos)** supuse que esto es para suavizar la descarga porque otras veces he descargado proyectos y vienen igual, el caso es que le pegue una "vendor" de un proyecto con la misma versión de synfony 3.2 y no me esta funcionando.

Ejecuto composer update para que me instale las dependencias que necesito y me da los siguientes errores.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya intenté modificando el memory_limit de mi **xampp** que es el servidor que uso, pero vi en otros posts que había que modificar también el php-cli pero 
**¿donde lo localizo?** porque si entro desde infophp.php me da la ruta donde están dos archivos el php.ini.developer y el php.ini.production ambos también los modifique sin éxito. Entonces **¿qué me sugieren hacer sobre este problema?** **¿donde encuentro ese php-cli?**

Bueno creí haber resulto el problema subiendo el valor del memory_limit = 200000M pero esto me funcionó solo para hacer el composer update y ahora no me funciona, he seguido lo que siguiera la documentación de composer https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors pero nada parece funcionar, ya intenté en un computador diferente y nada 
**¿alguien que me diga porque sucede esto?**

Answer (score 0):

Prueba eliminando la carpeta `vendor` y luego corre nuevamente `composer`.

De todas maneras te comparto [documentación](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors) relacionada con este tipo de error.

Comment: No habia visto que tambien agregaste la misma documentacion, espero que eliminando la carpeta `vendor` se solucione! exito!

Comment: Recuerda que si has modificado los archivos php.ini, tienes que reiniciar el servidor para que se registren los cambios. En cualquier caso, esto es un error de la ejecucion de composer. Te diria que probaras con `php -d memory_limit=-1 composer update`